# Powershell format output in table style

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to increase RAM size on all my DCs.
When job is done I would like to get a report with all DCs in a table format but I can’t do that. My output is below.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> foreach ($DC in $DCs_ALL){
$DC
(Get-ADDomain -Server $DC).NetBIOSName
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Cim_PhysicalMemory' -ComputerName $DC| Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum /1gb
}
DC1
MyDomain
32
DC2
MyDomain
32
DC3
MyDomain
32
DC4
MyDomain
32
DC5
MyDomain
32
DC6
MyDomain
32
```

What I would like to get is something like that:

```
DCname   NetBIOSName    RAM [GB]
------   -----------    --------
DC1      MyDomain       32
DC2      MyDomain       32
DC3      MyDomain       32
DC4      MyDomain       32
DC5      MyDomain       32
DC6      MyDomain       32
```

My variable looks like this:

```
$DCs_ALL = ('DC1',
'DC2',
'DC3',
'DC4',
'DC5',
'DC6')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `PSCustomObject`:

```
foreach ($DC in $DCs_ALL){
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    'DCName' = $DC
    'NetBIOSName'=(Get-ADDomain -Server $DC).NetBIOSName
    'RAM [GB]' = ((Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Cim_PhysicalMemory' -ComputerName $DC| Measure-Object -Property Capacity -Sum).Sum / 1gb)
  }
}
```